# Can you set a l limited time period for a Stripe plan?

Tags: stripe-payments

We are writing a Saas application that users will only use for 10 months.  Is there a way to define in the payplan API to limit the number of payments to take from the customer?

I have spent some time looking over the API but I just can't see it.  Perhaps I'm just overlooking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe's subscriptions will always charge indefinitely by default so you'd need some custom development to [cancel the subscription after a certain number of payments](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#creating-an-installment-plan). The solution would be to [use webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to be notified about events that happen in your Stripe account.

If you listen for the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event you can count how many times your customer has paid and then [cancel the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription) when you want to stop the payments.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can use a subscription schedule and set the `phases.iterations`
property: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-phases-iterations

And set the end_behavior to "cancel"

Here's the full guide: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules